# Can enums return string instead of an integer?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, enums

I want my enums to return string values. Not the Enum Description, they must be returning a string value, instead of an int. The code sample below is exactly what in my mind, but obviously doesn't compile.

```
public enum TransactionType
{
    CreditCard = "C",
    DebitCard = "D",
    CreditCardAuthenticationWithAuthorization = "CA",
    DebitCardAuthenticationWithAuthorization = "DA"
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you call your enum member exactly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't, what you can do is create a static class that "acts" a bit like an enum with string values:

```
public static class TransactionType
{
   public const string CreditCard = "C";
   ...
}
```

You can access them the same way then:

```
string creditCardValue = TransactionType.CreditCard;
```

Another option would be to work with the [DescriptionAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) in `System.ComponentModel` namespace, but then your enums still will have underlying numeric values, so maybe that's not entirely what you need.

Example:

```
public enum TransactionType
{
   [Description("C")]
   CreditCard,
   ...
}
```

Comment: About your edited answer, I discovered that solution too. But I want it to look just like an enum to the developer who's gonna use my API. I think on the second solution you need to access differently.

Comment: @NecatiHakanErdogan Yes, I think there's no other way to access them than to use some reflection. It's really inconvenient to get the descriptions.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way.
You can choose between int, long, byte, short - generally numeric types.

You can do "some cheat", only for `char` values (because `char` is implicity casted to int):

```
public enum MyEnum
{
   Value = 'a'
}
```