# cannot implicitly convert type string to int, enum

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do an enum of Morse like so:

```
public enum Morse : String
{
    medzera = "       ",          
    a=".-",               
    b="-...",              
    c="-.-.",
    d="-..",
    e=".",
    f="..-.",
    g="--.",
    h="....",
    i="..",
    j=".---",
    k="-.-",
    l=".-..",
    m="--",
    n="-.",
    o="---",
    p=".--.",
    q="--.-",
    r=".-.",
    s="...",
    t="-",
    u="..-",
    v=...-",
    w=".--",
    x="-..-",
    y="-.--",
    z="--..",
}
```

But it throws an error.

Comment: Might be too advanced of a topic but you can consider making Morse a ValueObject.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35792450/3410196

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't create an enum of strings but you use `Dictionary<char,string>`

```
Dictionary<char,string> letters = new Dictionary<char,string>(){
   {'a' , ".-"},
   .....
   {'z' , "--.."}
};
```

Usage would be something like

```
var input = "az";
var output = string.Join("/", input.Select(c => letters[c]));
```

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN:

> The approved types for an enum are `byte`, `sbyte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, or `ulong`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to have a `string` enum which is not possible. Every enumeration type has an underlying type, which can be any integral type except `char`. See [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum) for more information. You might want to check this post for alternative solutions [How to define an enum with string value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588384/how-to-define-an-enum-with-string-value)

Comment: so, if i want to have these strings there i can do it but i must add to every one some byte value pe? or it rly cant be done

Comment: @ArnyeMob nope it can't be ... not using `enum` see the linked documentation page